# Are the placeholders of Generics compiled as an actual data type?

Tags: c#, generics, cil, compiled, intermediate-language

My question relates to how exactly Generics (in C#) are compiled.

**Code sample**

```
public class MyClass<Foo>
{
    public void MyMethod(Foo test)
    {

    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Would the `Foo` type in `MyMethod` be compiled as a concrete type? I would imagine not as this would require multiple versions of the same class being created (should it be instantiated with different types), so I imagine a generic type is properly supported rather than just being syntax sugar?
2. On a low level, how are generics implemented? Are the generic values against a class/method stored as special hidden fields?

I think my assumptions are incorrect, but I'm trying to get a feel for the inner workings behind the scenes.

**Update**

If I understand this article correctly, a new class in the IL is created during runtime with the concrete types.

> As a result, the runtime generates another version of the generic type and substitutes a long in the appropriate locations in MSIL. Conversions are no longer necessary because each specialized generic class natively contains the value type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx

Comment: I don't think that question satisfies my questions above. Maybe it does to some people, but I think that question assumes more knowledge than I currently do of how the IL code might work.

Comment: If you're interested in the answer to questions like, *"On a low level, how are generics implemented?"*, it might be time to increase your familiarity with IL. :-)

Comment: Definitely. I sometimes view IL code to get a rough idea of what's going on, but I've never studied it. I think the answer I'm looking for here however is more related to runtime? I would think.

Comment: No, generics aren't handled at runtime. The answer to the linked duplicate contains a quote that specifically addresses that: *"We do the overload resolution once and bake in the result. [...] The IL we’ve generated for the generic type already has the method its going to call picked out."*